# WebRTC - RTCDataChannel's onmessage event is not firing

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, stun, turn

I am trying to write a basic implementation of WebRTC to send text data using `RTCDataChannel`.
My signalling is working properly. LocalDescription and RemoteDescription is set on both peers and icecandidate events fire properly and ice candidates are shared to both peers. DataChannel `onopen` event also gets fired. But, when I try to send message using `send()` function of RTCDataChannel the `onmessage` event doesn't get fired on the other peer.

This is how I am opening the data channel -

```
private openDataChannel() {
    this.dataChannel = this.peerConnection.createDataChannel(`myDataChannel_${this.username}`, { ordered: true, protocol: 'tcp', });
    this.dataChannel.onerror = error => console.log('Data Channel Error:', error);
    this.dataChannel.onmessage = message => {
      console.log('data channel message', message);
      this.messages.push(message.data);
    };
    this.dataChannel.onopen = event => console.log('data channel opened', event);
}
```

I am sending data using `this.dataChannel.send(this.msgToSend);`

And this is the part where I am creating the RTCPeerConnection -

```
this.peerConnection = new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: [{ urls: 'stun:stun.stunprotocol.org:3478' }]
});
console.log('RTCPeerConnection created');
console.log(this.peerConnection);

this.peerConnection.onicecandidate = event => {
    if (event.candidate) {
      console.log('onicecandidate', event)
      this.sendToServer({
        type: 'candidate',
        candidate: event.candidate
      })
    }
}

this.openDataChannel();
```

After creating `RTCPeerConnection` and calling `this.openDataChannel` I invoke the signalling server through which I set remoteDescription and localDescription on both peers.

I tried to debug with **chrome://webrtc-internals/** . In it I can see two data channels on both peers. And I can see messagesReceived count is incrementing everytime I am sending data from other peer. But, on js the `onmessage` event isn't firing
[image]

The thing I am suspecting here is that from *peer B* I am sending data via myDataChannel_B (since that is the data channel created there). On *peer A* **webrtc-internals** shows messagesReceived count under myDataChannel_B. But, on peer A I am subscribed to `onmessage` event of myDataChannel_A. This seems odd. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hi! did you find anything? We have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact same issue as well, and turns out I was creating a separate data channel on every side of the connection.

As outlined in the [createDataChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/createDataChannel#examples) examples, if you are attempting to create a data channel via either side of the connection, they will need to have a shared `id` value, such as `0`:

```
// Both sides
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection(options);
const channel = pc.createDataChannel("chat", { negotiated: true, id: 0 });
```

It's worth noting that the `ondatachannel` callback, or `datachannel` event, is only fired when a *remote peer* has created a data channel, not when you have created the channel locally.  When `negotiated` is set to true, the `ondatachannel` event is not fired.  See [datachannel event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/datachannel_event) for more details.

If you are successful, viewing [chrome://webrtc-internals/](https://chrome://webrtc-internals/) should only show **one RTCDataChannel**.